# existence of an object, and what will happen in this case

Tags: java, garbage-collection

let's say we have an Object from person:

```
Person p = new Person("andrea");
```

if I create now another object of P:

```
p = new Person("Sam");
```

what happen in this cas with Person Andrea? it will be removed from the Garbage Collector? or it will still be exists? if so how can i delete Object of Andrea?

Thanx for your Explanation an Help.

Comment: it will exist until the next garbage collection cycle.

Comment: You can't remove it. Even though it is part of any list or map, only references to this object shall be delinked when we remove from them. But ultimately they are collected by GC only once they are not referenced at all.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`p` is a reference that initially points to `Person` "andrea". Once you create a new `Person` and make `p` point to it, the `Person` object created earlier ("andrea") becomes *unreachable* and hence *eligible for GC*. When the actual Object will be GCed depends on the current JVM state and the GC being used.

Answer (score 5):

```
p = new Person("Sam");
```

Once you write this, you are overwriting the existing one and hence it is unreachable. Will be garbage collected soon.

Answer (score 1):

There is no way to force garbage collector to delete that object from heap. The only thing you can do is invoke garbage collection by writing `System.gc()`. 
But its up to scheduler when it will run the garbage collection.

Comment: Note that `System.gc()` could infact be ignored by the VM