# Object exists after assigning other object to the same variable

Tags: java, swing, garbage-collection

According to this answer to "[existence of an object, and what will happen in this case](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33363815/existence-of-an-object-and-what-will-happen-in-this-case/33363878#33363878)", when I create an object:

```
Person p = new Person("Andrea")
```

...and later I create:

```
p= new Person("Sam")
```

...the `Person` "Andrea" will be garbage-collected.

So, when I want to add 2 buttons to a `JPanel`, why I can do this?

```
Jbutton b = new Jbutton("add");
panel.add(b);
b = new Jbutton("ok");
panel.add(b);
```

According to the above topic, the "add" `JButton` object will be later deleted by the GC.  What happens in this case to the listeners I added to this `JButton`?

Comment: nope it wont get gc´d because `panel` holds a reference to the button with the text `add`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `JButton` object is referred to by the `b` reference variable;
when you create the new object `b` points to the new one correctly, and the older one is eligible for GC if no one refers to it, but here in your case, the older one is still referred to by the `panel` so it wasn't garbage collected.

Objects are only collected by the GC when not referred to by any live thread.

Comment: And what will happen when the object Andrea is static? As i know a static object can be initialized just one time At Programm runtime  . What will be happens with a static object that Not be used?

Comment: while static object came into picture, mean it  will live untill class available on memory. while class unload it will automatically destroyed.

Answer (score 2):

the object 'new JButton("add")' won't be GC,because it is still referenced by your main program .

although the variable "b" pointed to the other object, 'new JButton("add")' is pointed by other variable referenced from panel.

Answer (score 2):

An object will be eligible for garbage collector only if the object isn't being referenced by any other reference variable. However here, the panel holds the reference to the older JButton object, thus won't be removed.